# Linux centos : ping displays unknown host for any domain name

Tags: linux, centos, ping

Ping displays unknown host for any domain name.

It worked before this time true!!

Ping works for ip address but fails for domain names.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/521621/centos-dns-not-working-cannot-resolve-any-hostnames and http://serverfault.com/questions/367765/dns-problems-on-centos-fresh-install

Comment: Thanks. It was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Check what's in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
If there is no "nameserver" specified, you have to do that in order to resolve domains.
Example:

```
nameserver dns1.domainname.com
nameserver dns2.domainname.com
```

or you can use Google's public DNS servers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8   
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) edit /etc/resolv.conf, add

nameserver dns1.domainname.com

nameserver dns2.domainname.com

(2) another reason may due to /etc/nsswitch.conf

add dns in the hosts: xxx

[image]